# Approximate string matching in Ruby

Tags: ruby, approximate-nn-searching

I am implementing user search functionality in my Rails application. I want the application to suggest the correct spellings if the user makes a mistake in typing the spelling. Is there any plugin for this in ruby. Can this be done in sql?

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: Are you matching against a big dictionary or a small set of search terms?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [hunspell](http://rubyforge.org/projects/hunspell/) gem is there to help you.  It requires some external dependencies so it's not pure Ruby.  But according to this [readme](http://hunspell.rubyforge.org/svn/README) it seem to be exactly what you are looking for.

Alternatively, you can try [BOSSMan](http://www.funonrails.com/2010/08/spell-check-in-ruby-and-rails-using.html).  It looks like it spell checks via Yahoo.